# Reload the http parent window from a secure https pop up window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, https

I have a parent window under http and it opens a child popup window under https. I wanted to reload the parent from pop-up window using following Java Script.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    }
```

I found that this is not possible due to cross-domain scripting restrictions and HTTP->HTTPS is considered cross domain.

After searching in internet, i found the workaround for cross domain problem using following script,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.href = 'index.html';
        windoww.close()
    }
```

Above solution works well with Chrome. But in IE, instead of reload the url in the parent window, it opens in an new tab. I dont want it to open in new tab.

Please help me on this. Any alternative suggestions to achieving this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method
window.open('mypage.html','_self');
Second parameter will open the page in the same tab.
Should work fine in IE also,
For further information refer
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml